# Looking for official deep learning Docker images

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I'm looking for deep learning Docker images from official/trustful resources.

1. TensorFlow images on DockerHub are added by a community user and not TensorFlow/Google itself: https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/tags
2. PyTorch images on DockerHub are added by a community user and not PyTorch/Facebook itself: https://hub.docker.com/r/pytorch/pytorch/tags

On DockerHub there does not exist [TensorFlow](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=tensorflow&type=image) or [PyTorch images](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=pytorch&type=image) from "Verified Publishers" or "Official Images".

However in the case TensorFlow the official [TensorFlow website links](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker) to these images from point 1, which make it look "somehow" official. (I'm confused.)

Are they trustful? Are there other/better resources? Or do you build your own Docker images?
I'm looking forward for your help and advice.

Comment: If you look at docker user [`tensorflow`](https://hub.docker.com/u/tensorflow), you can see that it is indeed "Google, Inc. Mountain View, CA". That seems pretty official to me.

Comment: Yes you are right, that lines look official. But below every image you can read something like "Last updated a day ago by tensorflowpackages". When you click on it, you can see that it is a community user. From that step on I'm not sure anymore it it's official or not. (TensorFlow is no "Verified Publisher".) What so you think?

Comment: If you want to ask specific question Docker you can ask them here: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/124022/docker-container

Comment: Thanks @bjornsing, I will take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the **Tensorflow documentation**, the **TensorFlow Docker images** are **tested** for **each release** in the **Dockerhub**, thus you can consider this as `Trusted`.

However, I suggest that you **build your own Docker images in TensorFlow**:

The following command downloads the TensorFlow 2.0 release images into your machine.
Run any of these commands in your **PowerShell**:

```
docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow                     # latest stable release
docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:devel-gpu           # nightly dev release w/ GPU support
docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter  # latest release w/ GPU support and Jupyter
```

Please ensure you have **properly installed Docker** and Run it as an **Administrator**.

**1.1** Install the latest stable release.

`PS c:\Users\administrator1> docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow`

**1.2** Install nightly dev release w/ GPU Support

`PS c:\Users\administrator1> docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:devel-gpu`

**1.3** Install latest release w/ GPU support and Jupyter.

`PS c:\Users\administrator1> docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter`

**2.** Test the installation of the TensorFlow 2.0, run the command in the PowerShell.

`PS c:\Users\administrator1> docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter`

**3.** Demonstrate some TensorFlow Docker recipes.

**3.1** Start a bash shell session within a TensorFlow-configured container:

`PS c:\> docker run -it tensorflow/tensorflow bash`

Note: Type the python on the directory, simple tensorflow program and hit enter

```
root@03f668710f49:/# python
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> print(tf.__version__)
2.0.0
```

Or 
Note: Create a directory tmp and script.py with contains simple TensorFlow program.

`import tensorflow as tf,  print(tf.__version__))`

Then execute the command:

`PS C:\tmp>  docker run -it --rm -v ${PWD}:/tmp -w /tmp tensorflow/tensorflow python ./script.py`

**For using the Jupyter Notebook IDE:**

**4.** Start a Jupyter Notebook server using TensorFlow's nightly build with Python 3 support:

`PS C:\> docker run -it -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:nightly-py3-jupyter`

**5.** Copy and paste one of the URLs on the chrome/IE8 web browser.

`sample URL http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=fe9d924aeff07be3ddo74ffdc58b593e59d22d0d24c7188d`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The [Community Organization tensorflow](https://hub.docker.com/u/tensorflow) looks indeed trustful, but what is your argument that the containers added by the [Community User tensorflowpackages](https://hub.docker.com/u/tensorflowpackages) are trustful?